# append some element to html page via javascript in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

i want to create an infinite scroll in android webview, so when user scroll down he can see more of my local html, so i did the following:

when user reach the end i get body content of another page and store it as String in a ArrayList (each tag in one position) and attach them one by one the to current page via javascript.

all things works fine BUT, some body element wont attach and i get `Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 at null:1`.

here is the code:

```
for(String body : bodyChunks) //bodyChunks is ArraList of body elements like <p> tags.
{  
     if(!loadIntrupt)
     {
         String js = "javascript:(function() { document.body.innerHTML += '" + body + "';}())"; // load on bottom
         loadUrl(js);
     }

}
```

so one paragraph is attached and another wont!

**can anybody say what is the problem?**

here is my other post in this case: [infinite scroll in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113973/infinite-scroll-in-android-webview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first the `'`s in String should be replaced with `\'` :

```
body = body.replace("'", "\\'");
```

then all newline char should be eliminated:

```
body = body.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), " ");
```

all problem solved.