# Confused after WebView very slow on large data sets

Tags: android, html, webview, textview

After many days, I almost finished my first app but the `WebView` ruined it in the end. Search functionality is way too slow with it. 
The `HTML/CSS` page I wanted to display, after search, can sometimes become very big in size like one made with looping and concatenation over 7100 records from `DB`.

This takes forever for `WebView` to load.

I thought `WebView` would be easier option to start with as my data was `HTML/CSS`.

Now, I am considering to use some other way like `TextView` with `ScrollView` etc. I read that this needs my text to have all its apostrophe (') etc escaped.

Can anyone please suggest me what way should I take now. Please keep in mind that my data is going to be big. Like a user can search `data(Book)` that is about 25MB. So chances are something the user searches may be in all records that would be 25MB data needs to be displayed with smooth scrolling.

What is the best way to from here. I just need `WebView` to be replaced with some other `View`.

Thank you

**EDIT:**
I also have Arabic text along with English text, in case en/decoding should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the search and pagination on the server, and use something like infinite scrolling on the client. The problem is not the technology that you chose but how **you** use it. Sending 25 MB worth of data to the client, at once, is never going to go well.

Take a look at this:
[infinite scroll in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113973/infinite-scroll-in-android-webview)